# Training own classifiers using trainCascadeObjectDetector for face detection

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, machine-learning, face-detection, matlab-cvst

I want to train a cascade classifier to face detect. I read this [page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/train-a-cascade-object-detector.html). But I wont use trainingImageLabeler app, because I already have face and nonface database sized 24x24. How I use trainCascadeObjectDetector function with my own database?

Is there any example except this you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to train the classifiers with your own database, you will only need 'trainCascadeObjectDetector' function and feed your images into the proper arguments (Positive, negative images). The output classifier will be in your 'outputXMLFilename' as in  [traincascadeobjectdetector](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/traincascadeobjectdetector.html)

trainingImageLabeler is helpful function for classifying positive/negative image. Try this function later when you work with larger database.

Comment: Thanks for giving time. I am feeding images properly and it works, but has very bad performance. 
I think this function doesnt like images that have small size (like 24x24). Am I right?

Comment: If I use 24x24 negative image, training takes a few minutes an it ends at stage 3 of 20. So it doesnt give good performance. However I use a variant set of large images as negative example it works better. Why this happens? I have thousands of example images and I want to use these for training.

Comment: **1.** Yes, you are right. We use smaller images just for speed-up the training process. **2.** Larger set of negative images will tell the classifier what it should not decide in the wrong way. This will surely help.

Comment: The point is, if you appropriately feed the classifier. The results will be improved. Because the algorithm of it is the same. Try the alternate way to go.

Comment: I am trying to implement Viola Jones and all articles I read talks about image database that have a same small size. Therefore I think I should use a database like them. At the moment, I confused that which way is the best? What I should to do? Try another function or try large size random negative images?

Comment: Can you please explain well. Because my English not very good. Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to the tips to setting the parameters from MATLAB, playing with 'truePositiveRate' and 'FeatureType'.  
"LBP" or "Haar" might give the better result compared to "HOG(default)" <in face detection>.  
For further improvement, you should supply more positive/negative images and take times. See troubleshooting from your link for additional info.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is not matlab, but [this post about training a 'banana' detector](http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html) is really great and can give you some tips.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [tutorial](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/train-a-cascade-object-detector.html) on how to use `trainCascadeObjectDetector` in the documentation.